# Refactoring to dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, refactoring

I have a piece of code which I want to refactor into a dependency injection style.

It currently looks like this:

```
class MyService {
    public void A(Account account, String someparam1, int someparam2) {
        AccountHandler myHandler = new AccountHandler(account);

        // Do something with AccountHandler...
        myHandler.someMethod1(someparam1);
        myHandler.someMethod2(someparam2);
    }

    // Some more methods with same signature
}
```

One way would be to inject the `AccountHandler` and set the account for each method:

```
class MyService {

    @Inject
    AccountHandler myHandler;

    public void A(Account account, String someparam1, int someparam2) {
        myHandler.setAccount(account);

        // Do something with myHandler
        myHandler.someMethod1(someparam1);
        myHandler.someMethod2(someparam2);
    }
}
```

This seems weird to me. `AccountHandler` is (or could be) a singleton, but it would still have some state. Theoretically it would be possible in a different method to "forget" to call `setAccount` without issues because the previous service-method set it (unless you of course specify that it should be prototype-scoped, but still... seems weird).

```
class MyService {

    @Inject
    AccountHandler myHandler;

    public void A(Account account, String someparam1, int someparam2) {

        // Do something with myHandler
        myHandler.someMethod1(account, someparam1);
        myHandler.someMethod2(account, someparam2);
    }
}
```

This only pushes the issue to `AccountHandler`. Either `AccountHandler` would itself do a `this.setAccount(account)` at the beginning of the `someMethod1/2`, or alternatively it could have every method be side-effect free, meaning it doesn't actually have any state. This sounds okay-ish, but I'm feeling like I've misunderstood something.

What I think would be the most idiomatic would be something like:

```
class MyService {
    public void A(@Inject AccountHandler myHandler, String someparam1, int someparam2) {
        // Do something with myHandler
        myHandler.someMethod1(someparam1);
        myHandler.someMethod2(someparam2);
    }
}
```

Where `AccountHandler` would be something like:

```
class AccountHandler {
    @Inject
    Account account;

    public void someMethod1(String someparam1);
    public void someMethod2(int someparam2);
}
```

Somewhere before I call the `MyService` method I would put `Account` on the `IoC`-container's scope. I have no idea of how you'd actually do this in `Java`. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject an AccountHandlerFactory that has a createAccountHandler(Account) method, and the AccountHandlerFactory would be a singleton which is stateless and your AccountHandlers will be statefull but single objects.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought as well. Though after googling, the conventional wisdom seems to be that the _factory-pattern_ and _dependency injection_ are different solutions for the same problem. I have not seen anyone else use a factory inside for DI? I see that Spring has something called BeanFactory, though not sure if it is applicable in this use case.

Comment: Why not? I see it all the time, normally if you create a factory you will create a factory interface, for example you'd have a AccountHandleFactory interface with the method I mentioned, then you cound have DatabaseBackedAccountHandlerFactory and HttpBasedAccountHandlerFactory implementations which you can easily swap using a DI framewok. And also it makes you code much more testable. The BeanFactory is a spring specific thing, if you want to tightly couple with spring you can create a prototype scoped spring bean for AccountHandler

Comment: It took some thought, but yes, I agree. This is obviously the best solution. I do have some worries about what would happen if AccountHandler itself had other dependencies which I did not want the factory to handle. That is however a problem for another day.